# make the camera to wait untill the geo tag get attached to taken photo in android

Tags: android, camera, geotagging

how to make the camera application to wait until the Geo tags get attached to photo using any broad cast receiver?
The problem is: Open the camera app and switch on Geo tag feature in camera settings and start taking photo.If we continuously take photo, some photo are not get attached with Geo tags.

Reason for the problem is: android Need some time to attach geo tags to taken photo using camera. Because it has to use some sensors to identify the latitude and longitude position.If we continuously take photo, then android does not know which gps location to attach with which photo.

What to do: First we have to know whether the geo tag is on/off in camera settings?
next we have to make the camera to wait until the geo tag get attached to photo?We  have to notify the user if camera is waiting or not?

I am using the camera intent to takle photo in my code..
so help me how to solve the above problem in android through code?